# java.io.IOException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM on several devices

Tags: android, https, retrofit, okhttp, http2

I'm using Retrofit 1.9 in my Android app.

Server is on Django with Nginx, HTTPS with HTTP 2. Certificate is from WoSign, "A" score on SSL Labs.

I'm testing on 3 devices:

- Nexus 4, Android 5.1.1 (official)
- Nexus 9, Android 7.0 (official)
- Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.4 (official)

On SGS3 it works fine, but on Nexus 4 & 9 I'm getting the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.framed.FramedStream.getResponseHeaders(FramedStream.java:146)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http2xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http2xStream.java:150)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:87)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:722)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:576)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:287)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
                                                               at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
                                                               at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
                                                               at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
                                                               at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
                                                               at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
                                                               at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                               at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this. It's a Nginx [bug](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2506)

This issue was fixed in Nginx 1.11. So, the solution is just to update to NGINX 1.11 (mainline currently).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still having a problem (2018).

I've  solved that issue by updating retrofit version to

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, nginx was already updated to 1.11.x.  The culprit for me was okhttp and retrofit.  When I tried to make a PUT request, it would fail with `stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM`.

To fix it, I upgraded to the latest versions of both, which at the time I'm writing this are:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
```

If you're using retrofit 2.0.x or okhttp 3.1.x, upgrading should fix the issue.