# How to solve okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM in Retrofit POST request

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit to pass data to server. But getting following exception in response :

okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM

I referred following links for the above exception:
[java.io.IOException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM on several devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312946/java-io-ioexception-stream-was-reset-refused-stream-on-several-devices)

and updated retrofit and okhttp versions to following :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
```

Still issue is not resolved. How to fix it?

Comment: hello, i face the same problem ? did you find a workaround ?

Comment: Same problem :(

Answer (score 17):

It's too late to response and it's possible you got it the fix but in my case, I resolve the problem adding protocols in the `OKHttpClient`:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder(); 
httpClient.protocols( Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1) );
```

Regards!

Comment: If you want to know what's going on – most likely the problem is head of line blocking on bad networks. See https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/http2-issues.html and https://http3-explained.haxx.se/en/why-quic/why-tcphol